# Filter views on Current user OR Administrator

Tags: views

I have a total of 770 users, 760 with the custom role of `"certified provider"`, 10 with the role of `"certified administrator"`.

Using views, and relationships I am able to allow the certified provider to each see only their own created nodes. But I need the "certified administrator" to see ALL nodes from ALL providers. 
I have a `relationship of Content:Author`, and `filter of User:Current`. 
I have read everything I can get my hands on to figure out what to do  and where to go next.

Have tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840490/drupal7-filter-view-based-on-current-users-roles 
But haven't been able to get the filter values to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about just remove the filter of User:Current?

Comment: @Jimmy Ko When I remove the filter `User:Current`, then all the nodes are visible to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with multiple roles, make sure the access control module has all the correct control settings. In Admin->structure->Content Type->Access Control I had the `"View any **Content Type** content"` checked. As soon as I removed that, the suggestion by @Jimmy Ko, worked, Thanks Jimmy.
 Easy to overlook when you have 3 different places where the content type is limited.